# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers, Version=9.0.0.0,

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an MVC website hosted in Azure Websites, that when run locally, works great.

However, when I publish to Azure Websites, I get the error message:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Doing some research on this type of error, I see that it could possibly be related to either (a) referencing an incorrect version locally than one that is installed on Azure, or (b) a DLL is referencing `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers` as a dependency.

My issue is that I have no idea how to debug this. If the issue is caused by (a), how can I tell? If the issue is caused by (b) how ca `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers`?

I've been struggling with this for too many hours now, and googling doesn't seem to lend much help.

Has anyone encountered this error before?

**UPDATE**

Screenshot of my References folder. Nothing out of the ordinary in my opinion, but clearly something is going on.
[image]

Comment: Does this assembly get loaded when you run locally? If yes - try to figure out where you refer to it - should not be really be used in your app... Make sure no random binaries is in your "bin" folder (i.e. may be loaded if there is some reflection code that tries to load all assemblies for your app) or some test page that requires the assembly and get compiled in published site along with all other pages.

Comment: How can I tell if it gets loaded when I run locally? (I'm really new to this type of error, so I'm slowly learning how to debug)

Comment: There is probably a dependency on it by some other DLL you are referencing.

Comment: You could try http://www.dependencywalker.com/ on your DLLs that you are referencing.

Comment: While debugging locally - Debug -> Windows -> Modules

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Following your steps, no, `'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers` is not showing up in the loaded modules. Not sure what this means though.

Comment: @Brett Just wondering if you have tried referencing it in your app and copying it local on compile?

Comment: @Brett unfortunately it means that easy way to reproduce the problem did not worked out :( . No more ideas how to proceed at this point from me.

Comment: @Paul I have tried referencing locally `'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers` but the only version available through *Add Reference* is 10.0.0.0, and the error regarding missing version 9.0.0.0 on Azure still persists.

Comment: @Brett Hmm... bummer... Surely it must be in your GAC then? Dump your GAC and have a look (so you can try referencing it directly)... No1 suspect for me would be Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource try DependencyWalker on it, although it is a little outdated and can miss some 64bit dependencies, also the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights sounds suspect.

Comment: To get assemblies from the GAC try cd  c:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL xcopy . C:\GacDump /s /y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a weird one, and I'm still not sure of the actually reason.

I ended out completely deleting the website from Azure, and republishing, and it works fine.
This was an ok solution for my case because my website was in its infancy.